# Use PHP time() function in a class

Tags: php, time

This is surely a very easy question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I am writing a PHP class that needs to know what the current time is.

This code works:

```
class className{
    private $currentTime = 1475607467;
[...]
}
```

This code does not:

```
class className{
    private $currentTime = time();
[...]
}
```

What gives? Since "time()" is returning the same 10-digit number, shouldn't these be equivalent?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Have you tried setting the variable in the constructor as opposed to setting it inline?

Comment: Property declarations can only be constant values, not expressions. Use the constructor.

Comment: @mario: expression are allowed in recent PHP versions, but only ones that can be FULLY evaluated at compile-time. `$currentTime = 1+1` is an expression, but is valid. `= time()` isn't, because that value can't be satisfied while compiling. while PHP **COULD** call time() and save the time-of-compilation, that's almost certainly not what the code will be expect - they want "time at execution", not "time at compilation".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you populate that property in the constructor:

```
class className
{

    private $currentTime;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currentTime = time();
    }

    [...]
}
```

Take your time and read carefully [this section of PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) on class properties. This will save a lot of time for you in the future.

Answer (score 3):

As mario already pointed out, you cannot declare a property using an expression. So you can use the construct function to initialize the class properties:

```
class className{

    private $currentTime;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currentTime = time();
    }
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Class className
{
    private $currentTime;
    Function __construct()
    {
         $this-> currentTime = time();
    }
 }
```